# Uploading UTF-8 strings into Vertica

Tags: utf-8, vertica, data-import

I am trying to upload some UTF-8 strings into Vertica database using it's COPY command triggered by Vertica client (VSQL tool). Unfortunatelly, from Vertica docs:

> The drivers do not transform data loaded by executing a COPY or COPY LOCAL statement.

Data I am importing looks like this

```
\u00DCser entered \\t and \\n and \\r and \u0161 \u0111 \u017E \u010D \u0107 \u0160 \u0110 \u017D \u010C \u0106 \u00FC \u00F6 \u00E4 \u00DC \u00D6 \u00C4
```

This is just a set of some characters and represents one string being imported.
Does anyone has any idea how to do this?
Of course, there is an option of some sed-awk magic before triggering COPY command, if needed.

Comment: Are you asking if Vertica can translate the UTF-8 strings into Regular Text ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is not in utf-8 but in some kind of unicode point printable format. Check your extract process and make sure your data is in utf-8 and it will load fine (character data *must* be in utf-8 in vertica).